# Custom message builder to handle binary data - wso2 EI

Tags: wso2, binaryfiles, data-conversion, ei

1) I have an incoming message from IBM Legacy system, i need to convert it into XML/text and send it back to a client using WSO2 EI 6.1.1.

2) I am using apache kafka as a messaging queue here, hence i have created an inbound endpoint in wso2 EI.

3) I believe WSO2 EI by default doesn't have a binary builder, so i have written a custom message builder and added that JAR in EI_HOME/lib and added the message builder class in axis2.xml

4) I posted the binary message in to kafka topic, but still wso2 EI is not able to convert into desired format.

5) The message builder (logic) is working as a standalone java function and i can get expected response.

Any help to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The content-type given in axis2.xml should match the content type given in kafka inbound endpoint.
the class path should be added in axis2.xml